# Linux: List file names, if last modified between a date interval

Tags: linux, list, date, ls

I have 2 variables, which contains dates like this: 2001.10.10

And i want to use ls with a filter, that only list files if last modified were between the first and second date

Comment: look instead at the `find` command. It is good for specifying complex filters on a collection of files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it is not the simplest. I just now developed it, only for you. :-)

```
ls -l --full-time|awk '{s=$6;gsub(/[-\.]/,"",s);if ((s>="'"$from_variable"'") && (s<="'"$to_variable"'")) {print $0}}';
```

The problem is, that these simple commandline tools doesn't handle date type. So first we convert them to integers removing the separating "-" and "." characters (by you is it ".", by me a "-" so I remove both, this can you see in

```
gsub(/[-\.]/,"",s)
```

After the removal, we can already compare them with integers. In this example, we compare them with the integers $from_variable and with $to_variable. So, this will list files modified between $from_variable and $to_variable .

Both of "from_variable" and "to_variable" need to be environment variables in the form 20070707 (for 7. July, 2007).

Comment: the 2 date, that i need to compare is the value of my 2 variable, not a constant date

Comment: @user3063349 I upgraded the script. Now it uses the interval $from_variable until $to_variable .

Comment: my linux terminal isnt recognize it as valid syntax

Comment: What error do you see? Do you know what is an environment variable?

Comment: oops. Fixed. And now?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of involves creating temporary files with the boundary timestamps, and then using `find`:

```
touch -t YYYYMMDD0000 oldest_file
touch -t YYYYMMDD0000 newest_file
find -maxdepth 1 -newer oldest_file -and -not -newer newest_file
rm oldest_file newest_file
```

You can use the `-print0` option to `find` if you want to strip off the leading `./` from all the filenames.

If creating temporary files isn't an option, you might consider writing a script to calculate and print the age of a file, [such as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/169858/looking-for-a-shell-one-liner-to-display-the-age-of-a-file-in-days), and then using that as a predicate.

Comment: not problem to use temp files, but i havent got constant dates, i have dates in 2 variables, like 2010.10.10 syntax, so if u can solve this that would be awesome :)

Comment: You would need to insert the values of your variables into the `-t` argument to `touch`. I can't help you do that without knowing what programming language / script interpreter you're using, but it's a pretty straightforward operation.

Comment: thanks, its seems like working, but no way to list all the files like recurse, not only the folder u run the script?

Comment: If you want it recursive, remove the `-maxdepth 1` argument from the `find` command.